# How to use foreachPartition in Spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-structured-streaming

How to use below function in Spark Java ? Looked all over internet but couldnt find suitable example.

```
public void foreachPartition(scala.Function1<scala.collection.Iterator<T>,scala.runtime.BoxedUnit> f)
```

The only thing I know is that it is good for process `batch of data`, so called `BoxedUnit`.

How can I get `batch ID` or `BoxedUnit` of `dataset` to process data in batch ?

Can anyone tell how to implement this method ?

Comment: did you try convert your RDD to JavaRDD and then apply foreachpartition? which take a VoidFunction as parameter.

Comment: @ShemTov its not about voidfunction, I want to use it as it as it is. Curious to know how to get batchId to process batch of data from Dataset.

Comment: I guess you can implement the batchId by yourself, using acculomators - starting with zero and every batch at foreachPartition increment it by one. It`ll keep sync between all the executors and give you valid batchId.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you have the wrong impression of what `BoxedUnit` is and therefore insist on using the Scala interface in Java, which is overly complicated due to the amount of hidden complexity in Scala that gets exposed to Java. `scala.Function1<scala.collection.Iterator<T>, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>` is the implementation of `(Iterator[T]) => Unit` - a Scala function that takes an `Iterator[T]` and returns the `Unit` type. `Unit` in Scala is the equivalent of Java's `void`. `BoxedUnit` is the boxed version of `Unit` - it is a heap object holding the singleton unit value in its `UNIT` member and is an implementation detail that almost never surfaces in Scala programs. If the dataset is a `DataFrame`, then `T` will be `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` and you need to process Scala iterators over collections of `Row` objects.

To define something that is `scala.Function1<scala.collection.Iterator<Row>, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>` in Java, you need to create an instance of `AbstractFunction1<scala.collection.Iterator<Row>, scala.runtime.BoxedUnit>` and override its `apply()` method where you must return `BoxedUnit.UNIT`. You also need to make it serializable, so you usually declare your own class that inherits from `AbstractFunction1` and implements `Serializable`. You may also Java-fy it by exposing a different, more Java-friendly abstract method to be overridden later:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import scala.runtime.AbstractFunction1;
import scala.runtime.BoxedUnit;
import scala.collection.JavaConverters;
import java.util.Iterator;

class MyPartitionFunction<T> extends AbstractFunction1<scala.collection.Iterator<T>, BoxedUnit>
   implements Serializable {
   @Override
   public BoxedUnit apply(scala.collection.Iterator<T> iterator) {
      call(JavaConverters.asJavaIteratorConverter(iterator).asJava());
      return BoxedUnit.UNIT;
   }

   public abstract void call(Iterator<T> iterator);
}

df.foreachPartition(new MyPartitionFunction<Row>() {
   @Override
   public void call(Iterator<Row> iterator) {
      for (Row row : iterator) {
         // do something with the row
      }
   }
});
```

This is a fair amount of implementation complexity, which is why there is the Java-specific version that takes [`ForeachPartitionFunction<T>`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/api/java/function/ForeachPartitionFunction.html) instead and the above code becomes:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.function.ForeachPartitionFunction;
import java.util.Iterator;

df.foreachPartition(new ForeachPartitionFunction<Row>() {
   public void call(Iterator<Row> iterator) throws Exception {
      for (Row row : iterator) {
         // do something with the row
      }
   }
}
```

The functionality is **exactly the same** as the one provided by the Scala interface, just Apache Spark does the iterator conversion for you and it also provides you with a friendly Java class that doesn't require you to import and implement Scala types.

That said, I think you have a bit of misunderstanding of how Spark works. You do not need to use `foreachPartition` to process streaming data in batches. That is done automatically for you by the streaming engine of Spark. You write streaming queries that specify *transformations* and *aggregations* that then get applied progressively as new data arrives from the stream.

`foreachPartition` is a form of `foreach` reserved for some special batch processing cases, for example, when you need to do some expensive object instantiations in the processing function and doing it for each row incurs huge overhead. With `foreachPartition` your processing function gets called only once per partition, so you can instantiate the expensive objects once and then iterate over the partition's data. This decreases processing time because you do the expensive stuff just once.

But then, you cannot even call `foreach()` or `foreachPartition()` on a streaming source as that results in an `AnalysisException`. Instead, you have to use the `foreach()` or `foreachBatch()` methods of [`DataStreamWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/streaming/DataStreamWriter.html). `DataStreamWriter.foreach()` takes an instance of [`ForeachWriter`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/ForeachWriter.html) while `DataStreamWriter.foreachBatch()` takes a void function that receives a dataset and the batch ID. `ForeachWriter` receives an epoch ID in its `open()` method. Again, `foreachBatch()` comes in both Scala and Java flavours that are equivalent in functionality, so please use the Java-specific one if you are going to write in Java.

Comment: lliev, Is scala.Function1 type equivalent to MyPartitionFunction type ?

Comment: Is my understanding correct that BoxedUnit value of Dataset's partition is generated internally the moment foreachPartition is called and then following apply method is called  ? UNIT is something which is not in my hand to do but for internal reference. Correct ?

Comment: foreachPartition return nothing, Will it work as Action ?

Comment: @Maria, `BoxedUnit` is **NOT** a property of the dataset. It is an implementation of the *singleton pattern* - there is only one `BoxedUnit` instance and it is available via the static `UNIT` member. The instance is created by the Scala runtime. Scala is a functional programming language and each function must return a value, so `Unit` is a special value that is returned implicitly when the function does not return otherwise, i.e., the equivalent to `void` in Java. This has nothing to do with Spark - it is simply an implementation detail in Scala exposed to Java programs for interoperability.

Comment: Both `foreach()` and `foreachPartition()` are actions. They force Spark to evaluate the lazy transformations and then call a function for each row (`foreach()`) or partition (`foreachPartition()`) of the result. Both functions do not return any value - they are purely side-effect ones. They could, e.g., print values on the console (not very useful in a distributed environment) or update so-called accumulators. The latter is the most useful application of `foreach()`/`foreachPartition()`. If you want to transform the data and keep the result, use `select()` (better) or `map()`/`mapPartition()`.

Comment: `scala.Function1` is a trait, which is quite similar to a Java interface, but it also provides implementations of several methods related to functional composition. In Java, you **have** to subclass `AbstractFunction1` (which is an empty abstract class implementing `Function1`) to produce a function object that implements `Function1`. Since `MyPartitionFunction` is a subclass of `AbstractFunction1`, it does implement `Function1`.

Comment: you have cleared my doubt, thanks. I’ve one more doubt, curios to know. When we call foreachPartition where we pass MyPartitionFunction instance implementation, from where it receives the records to be processed by code implementation of MyPartitionFunction ...? Is there any already data structure holding dataset’s record present in foreachPartition ...? Because I can’t see any record passing in there but implementation only.

Comment: The `apply()` method gets called when the function object is called. So whenever you call the `foreachParitition` method, the driver serializes a bunch of `MyPartitionFunction` instances and sends them to the executors, which then call the `apply()` method passing it an iterator over all the data in the corresponding partition. Again, the `apply()` method is something that comes for the way Scala works. The equivalent Java-specific version of `foreachPartition` receives the iterator via the `call()` method of the `ForeachPartitionFunction` instance.

Comment: Cool..! Thanks Hristo ..! :)